# Facebook business news feed needs authenttication?

Tags: node.js, facebook, rss

I have a question about facebook business news feed.

So, I'm building my personal facebook business news feed in javascript (nodejs). But it is need authentication to fetch the rss. Anyone knows the options required should be send when requesting the business news feed?

Just to be clear, here is the link i want to fetch as rss from my app
https://www.facebook.com/business/news/rss/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like https://www.facebook.com/business/news/rss/ can be requested without any authentication. Unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for repliying. But that link need authentication. Try it without any logged in facebook account and it will display as blank white screen.

Comment: Even in a private tab, where I am not logged in to Facebook, I get to see the XML data of the feed when I request that URL. Doesn’t ask for authentication anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe thanks to keeping in touch this issue, I think you have fb cookies stored in your browser. Clear all of them and then go to the link. It is only blank white screen.

Comment: No, in a private tab I don’t have any cookies. And requesting the URL using a tool such as http://web-sniffer.net/, which doesn’t send any cookies either, still shows me the XML feed content. Can you show where you get any authorization prompt/error when requesting this URL? Screenshot?

Comment: @CBroe Here is the screenshot of my chrome (incognito) http://prntscr.com/94wqjs. And i'm using `feed-read` npm package in my app. It is returning html instead of xml of the rss feed. Here is what I got http://pastebin.com/ZGzQ7rQs. Have tried other rss, it works well except this one.

Comment: Is that URL potentially blocked where ever you are? I have no problems seeing the rss feed like @CBroe